# FedEx and Expresso Store Integration

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

I'm using Expresso's Store with Expression Engine and having trouble getting the FedEx shipping plugin to work with my test credentials. I set up a developer account with FedEx and entered the corresponding codes into the Store Settings. When I test using the sample store template, I receive an error "Error communicating with shipping provider."

Should I be testing using Test Mode = "False" or "True"?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening `store/libraries/store_shipping_fedex.php`, and around line 80 inside `calculate_shipping($order)`, add the following line:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($response); exit; // add this line
return $this->_parse_response($response);
```

Then run through your checkout process again (or just click "Update Totals"). That should print out the full response from FedEx, which should be helpful in diagnosing your issue.

If possible, update your question above with the response it returns, as it may be helpful to others.